# sql query to match all row with other row on same table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table that hold my products and services. I want to match every product with my services than i will assign base price to my services according to my product.

My table is as follows

```
ID  TypeID  Title
=========================
1   1   Product1
2   1   Product2
3   1   Product3
4   2   Service1
5   2   Service2
6   2   Service3
```

I want this table to return.

```
ProductID   ServiceID   ProductTitle    ServiceTitle
=========================================================
1       4       Product1    Service1
1       5       Product1    Service2
1       6       Product1    Service3
2       4       Product2    Service1
2       5       Product2    Service2
2       6       Product2    Service3
3       4       Product3    Service1
3       5       Product3    Service2
3       6       Product3    Service3
```

how can i do that with Ms SQL 2008??

Comment: You would need a join statement, but without the second table we can't give you an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
   P.ID ProductID, S.ID ServiceID, P.Title ProductTitle, S.Title ServiceTitle
FROM
(SELECT ID, Title
FROM tbl
WHERE TypeID = 1) P
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT ID, Title
FROM tbl
WHERE TypeID = 2) S
ORDER BY P.ID, S.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

`CROSS JOIN` returns the cartesian product of both table.

```
SELECT  a.ID ProductID, 
        a.Title ProductTitle, 
        b.ID ServiceID, 
        b.Title ServiceTitle
FROM    tableName a
        CROSS JOIN tableName b
WHERE   a.TypeID = 1 AND
        b.TypeID = 2
ORDER   BY a.ID, b.ID
```

Comment: but first answer gets candy ((:

Answer (score 0):

Following query may help you:

```
SELECT Product.ProductID , Product.ProductTitle , ProductType.Title
FROM dbo.Product INNER JOIN dbo.ProductType 
ON Product.ProductTypeID = ProductType.ID
```